# apt-get doesn't work on kali linux v2.0

Tags: apt, kali-linux, dependencies

For example, when i type `apt-get install tor` i get :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libpcap0.8-dev : Depends: libpcap0.8 (= 1.3.0-1) but 1.6.2-2 is to be installed
libsqlite3-dev : Depends: libsqlite3-0 (= 3.7.16.2-1~bpo70+1) but 3.8.7.1-1+deb8u1 is to be installed
tor : Depends: libseccomp2 (>= 0.0.0~20120605) but it is not going to be installed
      Recommends: tor-geoipdb but it is not going to be installed
      Recommends: torsocks but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Even when i type `apt-get -f install tor` i get the same error !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the local repository was out of date, solved after typing :

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Comment: I'm running into the same issue after adding jessie sources to sources.list, except instead of saying `is not going to be installed` it says `is not installable.` Did you use different sources? `apt-get clean` does not fix it for me.

Comment: Try to use [this](http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories) source list and run `apt-get clean` again (i used this source list too)

Comment: hm, if I add the non-free repos, nothing changes, and when removing tor jessie repos, I lose the installation candidate as expected. I'll keep tinkering